# Build a x/y Table with QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to create a x/y Table out of my QUERY Database.
I just don't know how to do that or what to google for..
It should be possible to create a graph like on the right side.
And I guess I can only do this by creating such a chart above,
which I have no clue how to build that..

[image]

Here the Google Sheet to play with:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1prpRS-NHXSXPxzcSh2pgvHiOatkkyIO5Qb0QRDQrWsY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pivot inside QUERY to achieve a result like that:

```
=QUERY(B4:D;"SELECT C,SUM(D) where C is not null group by C pivot B";1)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to add with this formula below the employees a Total revenue sum?

Comment: You could try wrapping in LAMBDA and using BYROW: `=LAMBDA(quer,{quer, BYROW(quer, LAMBDA(each, SUM (each)))})(put here the query)`